# SpagoBI SDK how to get the entire datasets & extract info from them through webservices?

Tags: web-services, spagobi

Is it possible to get a dataset through WS against SpagoBI SDK? All that I  got were just some documents but I was wondering if I could do that with Datasets as well.

From the website I can see

"The services available through web service are:
Data Set: it allows to receive the data sets, defined in SpagoBI, and their respective metadata."

http://www.spagoworld.org/xwiki/bin/view/SpagoBI/SpagoBISDK

I'd really appreciate any help.

What I want to do is just to integrate some other external tools on my project. I though SpagoBI would be nice to be a kind of Back-Office to manage any Dataset from different Datasource

Bye

Comment: have you done some work with your problem? i'm trying to figure out if can i call spagobi sdk from my cordova app

Comment: Yes, I was able to get all the entire datasets from requests in json format...It is for a long time I am not using this any more, but I remember they are exposing datasets through WS as I was asking. Finally, I got it but I move away from SpagoBI. Let me know if I can help you

Comment: Please provide a link having example of using webservice as a datasource. I am using spagoBI 5.0 because i was not able to pass parameter from Analyitcal driver in 5.2.